# Converting Mozilla DeepSpeech model to use in tensorflow.js environment

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js, mozilla-deepspeech

I have been attempting to convert a Mozilla Deepspeech trained model for use in tensorflow.js, in ml5.js soundClassifier layer. My understanding is that Mozilla DeepSpeech uses TensorFlow. I have been trying to follow the hints found here:

https://www.tensorflow.org/js/tutorials/conversion/import_saved_model

https://www.tensorflow.org/js/guide/conversion

`tensorflowjs_converter --help`

I have downloaded the DeepSpeech model from here:

https://github.com/mozilla/DeepSpeech/releases/download/v0.6.1/deepspeech-0.6.1-models.tar.gz

and after unpacking, the following files are found:

`lm.binary      output_graph.pb     output_graph.pbmm   output_graph.tflite trie`

I have attempted to run commands such as:

`tensorflowjs_converter --output_format=tfjs_graph_model --saved_model_tags=serve deep/ tensorflow.js/`

and variations to do the conversion.  `tensorflow.js/` is a directory I created, `deep/` is the directory containing the DeepSpeech model files (which are listed above.)

I get error:

`SavedModel file does not exist at: deep/saved_model.pb/{saved_model.pbtxt|saved_model.pb}`

I renamed, eg, `output_graph.pb` to `saved_model.pb`.

Firstly, I would like to know if the DeepSpeech model is even compatible with the tensorflowjs_converter, and if so, what am I missing to get this thing working.

Comment: NOTE: To the S.O. community, I know that this is not technically a programming question.  Please note that I am only posting here because this is the thread pointed to on the TensorFlow community page for getting technical questions answered ("Get Help => Technical Questions") found on this page: https://www.tensorflow.org/community.  Please be kind :-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i believe the `output_graph.pb` is a frozen model. in which case, you would need to run the converter like such:

```
tensorflowjs_converter \
    --input_format=tf_frozen_model \
    --output_node_names='logits' \
    deepspeech/output_graph.pb \
    tensorflowjs
```

however, doing this results in the following error:

```
ValueError: Unsupported Ops in the model before optimization
BlockLSTM, Mfcc, AudioSpectrogram
```

the operations `BlockLSTM`, `Mfcc`, and `AudioSpectrogram` are currently not supported by TensorFlow.js so the conversion will fail:

- https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs/issues/1728